# Spring Data - Customer @Query with no property matching

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to set up a custom @Query that is not automatically generated, but no matter what I try it is trying to match properties in the method name to those in my returning object.

How can I run through this query without it trying to build the query, and fail with a org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException? Perhaps @Query is the wrong annotation?

My repo currently looks like this:

```
@Repository
public interface ScheduleRepository extends CrudRepository<Schedule, Integer>
{
    @Query
    List<Schedule> findByTypeAndAirDateBetweenOrderByAirDateDesc(String type, Date startDate, Date endDate);

    @Query("SELECT s FROM Schedule s WHERE s.type = 'A' AND (s.airDate BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate) ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(s.airDate, NOW())) LIMIT 1")
    List<Schedule> findCurrentAd(Date startDate, Date endDate);
}
```

The exception occurs when it cannot find a matching 'current' field in my Schedule class. I don't want it to. I just want it to run the query as I've defined it, no questions asked.

As you've probably discerned, I'm new to Spring MVC & Data.

Thanks for anyone's help!

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem @Dave V?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using binding parameters, like `:VALUE`, you should use `@Param("value")` to match your `@Query` annotation. Try this:

```
@Repository
public interface ScheduleRepository extends CrudRepository<Schedule, Integer>
{
    @Query
    List<Schedule> findByTypeAndAirDateBetweenOrderByAirDateDesc(String type, Date startDate, Date endDate);

    @Query("SELECT s FROM Schedule s WHERE s.type = 'A' AND (s.airDate BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate) ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(s.airDate, NOW())) LIMIT 1")
    List<Schedule> findCurrentAd(@Param("startDate") Date startDate, @Param("endDate") Date endDate);
}
```

If you choose to use the constructor without @Param annotation, you can use `?n` binding like this:

```
@Repository
public interface ScheduleRepository extends CrudRepository<Schedule, Integer>
{
    @Query
    List<Schedule> findByTypeAndAirDateBetweenOrderByAirDateDesc(String type, Date startDate, Date endDate);

    @Query("SELECT s FROM Schedule s WHERE s.type = 'A' AND (s.airDate BETWEEN ?1 AND ?2) ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(s.airDate, NOW())) LIMIT 1")
    List<Schedule> findCurrentAd(Date startDate, Date endDate);
}
```

the ?n binding represent the sequence of parameters in your method. ?1 = startDate, ?2 = endDate.

Reference: [Spring Docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html#jpa.query-methods.at-query)